ServiceEndpoint timing out incorrectly
Im making a request to a third party API using a service generated in Visual Studio, however I keep getting timed out incorrectly. The below error message was received when the service endpoint was configured as such:
_client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);
_client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);
_client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);
_client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);
_client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0, 0);



 The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 22.23:59:09.8753653. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I've set it to 23 days as an extreme for testing, but from the error, it looks as though the request is treating the days value as a seconds value, i.e timing out after 23 seconds, not 23 days.
StackTrace Exception text
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

InnerException StackTrace and Message
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ValidateResponseStatusCode()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ParseIncomingResponse(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at 
    
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.ReceiveReplyAsync(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    

Inner Exception message:
GatewayTimeout Gateway Time-outs
     

I'm hoping this is just a configuration issue and not a bug?
Endpoint is type System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint .NET7
From the generated code:
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.2.0-preview1.23462.5")]


22.23:59:09.8753653 is 23 days minus 41-ish seconds. What library are you actually using? The soap-client tag is too generic. ServiceModel suggests you're using WCF, but no WCF tools (like svcutil) come with the .NET Core SDK itself. .NET 5+ are actually .NET Core versions. dotnet-svcutil is a separate download while the svcutil.exe tool is not meant for .NET Core. PS: .NET 7 is already out of support, it was never a Long-Term-Support version. The current LTS version is 8. The previous LTS is 6 and goes out of support in November 2024

I can't reproduce the problem when calling a public service with a client created by dotnet-svcutil on .NET 8. Without an explicit timeout, the default 1 minute is more than enough. When I reduce that to 1ms I do get a timeout. What's the actual exception you get from the call? Please post code others can use to reproduce the problem, eg code calling a public service. I used http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso

At the very least post the full exception text, not just the message. The full text includes any inner exceptions and the call stack that shows which calls led to the exception

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comments, I've added the StackTrace, but as you can see, not much information. I'm stuck with .NET7 at present due to it bein gan Umbraco V12 project,. The services calls were generated from within Visual Studio via a wsdl. It is using Svcutil to generate the code as per the attributes I've added to the questions. Thanks for your help in advance.

I think the problem might be a binding override. It may also be repeated in web.config. It is recommended that you add a log to see what is going on at the runtime to locate the error.Tracing and Message Logging
